# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: SIGSEGV, libjvm

Tags: java, 17.04, eclipse

I am using Eclipse 4.6.3 and Ubuntu Budgie 17.04.

I am trying to call a method from another class. In that method I have done some opencv task. But whenever I tried to call and compile, it shows this message:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f711102daf7, pid=7567, tid=0x00007f70b010d700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b11) (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.17.04.3-b11)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x67daf7]  jni_GetStringUTFChars+0x87
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/aritra/workspace/ProjectHetero/hs_err_pid7567.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

I have checked my method separately. It works fine. I have also checked previous questions asked about this same issue and changed in `config.ini` file by adding this. [Eclipse continue crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203771/eclipse-continue-crashing)

```
org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
org.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/home/aritra/Desktop/XUL RUNNER/xulrunner
```

I tried to write in `eclipse.ini`:

```
Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

But then it is not letting me open Eclipse. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Solved: I was passing null values to my methods that's why I was getting this error message.